# Python subroutine returning NonType

Tags: python, variables, subroutine

So I have created this fruit machine in python and when I call the variable to check the results of the machine the subroutine returns a non type error

I have tried to force the returned variable into a float (what I need it to be ) a couple ways but no luck
I am not sure what else to try: I have looked on a multitude of websites and asked friends for help but with no luck; I have tried to rewrite how the function is called but no change; how the return functions return the winnings variable but noting has changed. I have copied the code below.

```
import random
money = 1.00
finish = False


print (" You have £", money)

def prizecheck(tocheck,winnings):
    if wheel1 == tocheck:
        if wheel2 == tocheck:
            if wheel3 == tocheck:
                if tocheck == "Skull":
                    winnings = 0
                    return winnings
                    print ("The house wins, All money lost")
                elif tocheck == "Cherry" or tocheck == "Lemon" or tocheck == "Orange" or tocheck == "Star":
                    print ("You win £1")
                    winnings = winnings + 1
                    return winnings
                elif tocheck == "Bell":
                    print ("You win £5")
                    winnings = winnings + 5
                    return winnings
            else:
                if tocheck == "Skull":
                    winnings = winnings - 1.00
                    return winnings
                elif tocheck == "Cherry" or tocheck == "Lemon" or tocheck == "Orange" or tocheck == "Star" or tocheck == "Bell":
                    print ("You win 50p")
                    winnings = winnings + 0.50
                    return winnings
        elif wheel3 == tocheck:
            if tocheck == "Skull":
                print ("The house wins, you lost £1")
                winnings = winnings - 1.00
                return winnings
            elif tocheck == "Cherry" or tocheck == "Lemon" or tocheck == "Orange" or tocheck == "Star" or tocheck == "Bell":
                print ("You win 50p")
                winnings = winnings + 0.50
                return winnings
    elif wheel2 == tocheck:
        if wheel3 == tocheck:
            if tocheck == "Skull":
                print ("The house wins, you lost £1")
                winnings = winnings - 1.00
                return winnings
            elif tocheck == "Cherry" or tocheck == "Lemon" or tocheck == "Orange" or tocheck == "Star" or tocheck == "Bell":
                print ("You win 50p")
                winnings = winnings + 0.50
                return winnings
            
def spin():
    picture = random.randint(1,6)
    if picture == 1:
        wheel = "Cherry"
    elif picture == 2:
        wheel = "Bell"
    elif picture == 3:
        wheel = "Lemon"
    elif picture == 4:
        wheel = "Orange"
    elif picture == 5:
        wheel = "Star"
    else:
        wheel = "Skull"
    return wheel

    


while money >= 0.2 and finish != True:
    money = money - 0.2
    wheel1 = spin()
    wheel2 = spin()
    wheel3 = spin()
    print(wheel1,"|",wheel2,"|",wheel3)
    
    change = prizecheck("Skull",money)
    change = prizecheck("Cherry",money)
    change = prizecheck("Bell",money)
    change = prizecheck("Lemon",money)
    change = prizecheck("Orange",money)
    change = prizecheck("Star",money)
    
    money = change
    
    print("You have £",money)
    
    endcheck = input("Spin again (1), or quit(2)?")
    if endcheck == "2":
        finish = True
    
    if money < 0.20:
        print("Sorry You have ran out of money")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide full error traceback.

Comment: When you do `prizecheck(XXXXX,money)` and neither  `wheel1`, `wheel2` or `wheel3` is XXXXX you end up with `change = None`

Comment: You should try to convert this into OOP.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to think about how to determine winnings by looking at the count of the most frequent wheel value. For example, I believe all these produce the same "win" right?

```
["Cherry", "Cherry", "Lemon"]
["Cherry", "Lemon", "Cherry"]
["Lemon", "Cherry", "Cherry"]
```

If we find the count of the most frequent item found, in all cases we get: `("Cherry", 2)` making it easier to check and process.

I propose:

```py
def prize_check(wheels, bet_amount):
    ## ---------------------
    ## find the details of the most common item
    ## ---------------------
    most_common_value, most_common_count = collections.Counter(wheels).most_common(1)[0]
    ## ---------------------

    ## ---------------------
    ## All items different
    ## ---------------------
    if most_common_count == 1:
        return bet_amount  # a guess by me at what to return here
    ## ---------------------

    ## ---------------------
    ## Two of the items are the same
    ## ---------------------
    if most_common_count == 2:
        if most_common_value == "Skull":
            return bet_amount - 1.0
        return bet_amount + 0.5
    ## ---------------------

    ## ---------------------
    ## All three the same
    ## ---------------------
    if most_common_value == "Skull":
        return 0

    if most_common_value == "Bell":
        return bet_amount + 5.0

    return bet_amount + 1.0
    ## ---------------------
```

Then rather than calling `prizecheck()` multiple times, we call this new method once and pass in the wheel values and the bet.

```py
money = prize_check([wheel1, wheel2, wheel3], money)
```

Comment: was going to suggest using `Counter` as well, but judging by OPs code was concerned it would be too much of a jump

Comment: @SamMason Agreed. Hopefully my comments make it clear what the new method is doing so that the overall effect is a simplification for the OP rather than confusion.

Comment: it's certainly much clearer, there's only a dozen lines of actual code now.  use of features is good, certainly better than the comment suggesting that it be converted "into OOP"!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic gets to the end of `prizecheck()` without returning anything, setting `change` to `None` when you do `change = prizecheck(...)`.

Try to put a debug statement there and see when this happens.

Try to print the value of `change` every time you change it so you can see the pattern.

Get in the habit to always `return` something at the end of functions you expect a return value from.

Python is not a statically typed language so you can't force a value to be a float. If you could (in another language), you'd have to specify the return type of the function, and get a compiler error in the process. You can provide a type hint to check for mistakes like this, but a Python variable can always be set to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```py
import random

money = 1.00
finish = False

print("You have £", money)


def prizecheck(tocheck, money):
    winnings = 0  # Initialize winnings to 0
    if wheel1 == tocheck and wheel2 == tocheck and wheel3 == tocheck:
        if tocheck == "Skull":
            print("The house wins, All money lost")
        elif tocheck in ["Cherry", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star"]:
            print("You win £1")
            winnings = 1
        elif tocheck == "Bell":
            print("You win £5")
            winnings = 5
    elif (wheel1 == tocheck) + (wheel2 == tocheck) + (wheel3 == tocheck) == 2:
        if tocheck == "Skull":
            print("The house wins, you lost £1")
            winnings = -1
        elif tocheck in ["Cherry", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star", "Bell"]:
            print("You win 50p")
            winnings = 0.5
    return money + winnings


def spin():
    picture = random.randint(1, 6)
    if picture == 1:
        wheel = "Cherry"
    elif picture == 2:
        wheel = "Bell"
    elif picture == 3:
        wheel = "Lemon"
    elif picture == 4:
        wheel = "Orange"
    elif picture == 5:
        wheel = "Star"
    else:
        wheel = "Skull"
    return wheel

while money >= 0.2 and not finish:
    money -= 0.2
    wheel1 = spin()
    wheel2 = spin()
    wheel3 = spin()
    print(wheel1, "|", wheel2, "|", wheel3)

    money = prizecheck("Skull", money)
    money = prizecheck("Cherry", money)
    money = prizecheck("Bell", money)
    money = prizecheck("Lemon", money)
    money = prizecheck("Orange", money)
    money = prizecheck("Star", money)

    print("You have £", money)

    endcheck = input("Spin again (1), or quit(2)?")
    if endcheck == "2":
        finish = True

    if money < 0.20:
        print("Sorry, you have run out of money")
```

- Any print statements after return statements will not be executed, so I moved those
- I also simplified your `if` statements, less nesting makes it less confusing
- You were overwriting `change` each time you call `prizecheck` for different fruits. This means that only the last fruit's result will be stored in `change`. You need to accumulate the changes for all fruits and then update `money` accordingly
- In the `prizecheck` function you are using a variable named `winnings` defined outside the function. This causes a problem where you are not updating the money variable correctly. You need to pass `money` to the function and return the updated value

Comment: Good point, edited my answer